How to enable sched_ext config when compiling the kernel
I am trying to compile a kernel with sched_ext enabled. The mainline repo hasn't merged it yet but this tag on the sched_ext repo is a kernel source with sched_ext code.
As per the official documentation, I should compile this kernel with this config enabled:
CONFIG_SCHED_CLASS_EXT=y

I run these commands in the directory where I downloaded the aforementioned tag's source:
sudo make localmodconfig

I press enter on all the prompts
Then I use sudo vim to add this line to the end of the .config file:
CONFIG_SCHED_CLASS_EXT=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                

I save and use less to make sure that the extra line has been added. I then run
sudo make oldconfig

and to my surprise, the two config lines I had added are deleted!
So I reapply my custom lines to .config and avoid using oldconfig. I then run
sudo make -j4

and let it run for a while. I stop it mid-way and use less to check my .config. Again, my two config lines have disappeared!
I did the experiment again but this time only added a single line for the CONFIG_SCHED_CLASS_EXT=y config. I got the same results: make and oldconfig both delete my custom config line.
I also used sudo make menuconfig to explore the config options but didn't find anything related to sched_ext. This made me suspect if this config even exists. I used grep to find its definition and found this excerpt in ./kernel/Kconfig.preempt:

config SCHED_CLASS_EXT
bool "Extensible Scheduling Class"
depends on BPF_SYSCALL && BPF_JIT && DEBUG_INFO_BTF
...

The config is also used in multiple places in the code. So I know the source should support sched_ext. What am I doing wrong then?

The problem is that each kernel config might have prerequisites, i.e. other configs that have to be turned on before it becomes available. Turns out my problem was that the necessary prerequisites for CONFIG_SCHED_CLASS_EXT were off, so it wasn't showing up in menuconfig and couldn't be turned on using vim.
To see what prerequisites you need for a command, run make menuconfig, and in the menu that is opened, type a slash "/", this opens a search bar so you can search for configurations. type out the name of your configuration, and press Enter. The opened window shows you the status of the config itself, its prerequisites, and its location in the submenus.
